# Can't connect to MySQL database from java but able to connect from plain MySQL command line

Tags: mediawiki, mamp-pro, wiktionary

I'm trying to use **mwdumper** jar to import a wiktionary dump to a db that I created with MAMP Pro. Here is the command that I'm struggling with:

```
java -jar mwdumper-1.25.jar --format=sql:1.5 /Users/med/Downloads/enwiktionary-20171001-pages-articles-multistream.xml --output=mysql://localhost:8889/wiktionay?user=wikiuser&password=wiki2017
```

Running the jar with this command gives the following:

```
> [1] 1209
$ Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Access denied for user 'wikiuser'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
        at org.mediawiki.dumper.Dumper.connectMySql(Dumper.java:225)
        at org.mediawiki.dumper.Dumper.openOutputFile(Dumper.java:211)
        at org.mediawiki.dumper.Dumper.main(Dumper.java:96)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'wikiuser'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1074)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4074)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4006)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:919)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.proceedHandshakeWithPluggableAuthentication(MysqlIO.java:1694)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.doHandshake(MysqlIO.java:1244)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.coreConnect(ConnectionImpl.java:2397)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2430)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2215)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:813)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:47)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:399)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:334)
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:270)
        at org.mediawiki.dumper.Dumper.connectMySql(Dumper.java:221)
        ... 2 more
```

When I simply try to connect to the DB from the terminal, I have no access problem:

```
$ /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysql -u wikiuser -p
```

As mentioned in related issues, I checked "Allow network access to MySQL" from the MAMP Interface but still it didn't help. Same issue by using root.

Any idea what's wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem is that due to **&** operator **password** in the URL gets as separate command while sending URL on terminal. Hence, mysql never gets **password**.

Use **\** to escape **&** i.e.

```
--output=mysql://localhost:8889/wiktionay?user=wikiuser\&password=wiki2017
```

**Edited: 04:14 AM, IST**

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
>   Expected file stream, got SQL connection?

Try passing stream filename at the end i.e. after **--output** followed by **--format** and then `/Users/med/Downloads/enwiktionary-20171001-pages-articles-multistream.xml`

Comment: Thx! It solved that issue. Now I got another one:
`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Expected file stream, got SQL connection?`

Comment: Something funny: to debug the same command, escaping **&** leads to the error and without escaping works like a charm. Any explanation for that?